# Android ime actionGo doesn't work on certain devices

Tags: java, android

ime actionGo simply won't work on certain devices, like the HTC Evo 4G.  It works on Motorola Atrix and Droid X.

Here is the code:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"
            android:password="true"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"/>


TextView.OnEditorActionListener listener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView exampleView, int actionId, KeyEvent event) 
        {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO)
            {
                loginValidation();
            }

            return true;
    }};

    password.setOnEditorActionListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. Different manufacturers make a customized keyboard for their phone which may not completely behave as the android standard keyboard. This issue has been raised before. Most people overcome this issue by either overiding the onKey event or using a TextWatcher class. A bug has been filed about this

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2882

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this recently and if you're not worried about the user being able to add lines via the keyboard this worked for getting the "Go" button to show up:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: It works after specifying the `singleLine` attribute :) Thanks.